# How to transfer finished Vue app to symfony?

Tags: vue.js, symfony, symfony4

i got almost fully finished Vue frontend app and i need to move it inside symfony. I am already using webpack-encore bundle and i kinda have it. But when i am importing Vue inside an axios or vuetify plugin it gets me an error. U gues there is some problem with that encore. It looks like it doesnt know where to search so its not looking into node_modules.
I am using Symfony 4 and Vue 2.

I already am using webpack-encore but i am not shure if that is the right way.

Hopefully someone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You are some possibility

- First, you just can use your vuejs front app like an independant SPA and your back like an API with api platform.
  You can call your API with axios...
- Second : https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/vuejs.html

Comment: Yeah i know that, but because of how i got it i need it to be under one repository and inside the symfony app itself.
And for the second part - I already checked this and I did almoust everything of that. But i got errors from plugin/vuetify and plugin/router files. 
The errors are about that the Vue is not imported but I am importing it. It looks like it doesn't know where to look (node_modules).